How to fill countries with color on three js sphere
So I'm trying to make a Globe component with map on it where I can paint countries in different color. I managed to make it so border color is changeable but all the time I try to paint inside with Shapes I end up either having map being flat in the middle of the sphere or when I properly wrap my sphere with a map some fillings go under the sphere mesh and are not being fully filled.
I can solve it by changing elevation so map doesn't touch the sphere but then it looks not exactly how I want.
Can someone help me to figure out how to do? I also don't have much of experience with webgl to be honest.
Here is my current component code, would to figure out how to make those countries that are in the code have painted border to have filling inside too
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { json } from "d3-fetch";

function Globe() {
  const meshRef = useRef();
  const [geoJson, setGeoJson] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    json(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson"
    )
      .then((data) => {
        setGeoJson(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching GeoJSON:", error));
  }, []);

  useFrame(() => {
    if (meshRef.current) {
      // Rotate the globe
      meshRef.current.rotation.y += 0.015;

      // Smoothly adjust the tilt using a sinusoidal function
      const tiltAngle =
        (Math.sin(meshRef.current.rotation.y / 3) * Math.PI) / 12; // Max tilt 15 degrees
      meshRef.current.rotation.x = tiltAngle;
    }
  });

  if (!geoJson) return null;

  const radius = 3; // Radius of the globe
  const elevation = 0.01; // Elevation above the globe surface

  const latLonToVector3 = (lat, lon, radius, elevation = 0) => {
    const phi = (90 - lat) * (Math.PI / 180);
    const theta = (lon + 180) * (Math.PI / 180);

    const x = -(radius + elevation) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    const y = (radius + elevation) * Math.cos(phi);
    const z = (radius + elevation) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

    return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
  };

  const createCountryBorders = (coordinates) => {
    const shapeVertices = coordinates[0].map(([lon, lat]) =>
      latLonToVector3(lat, lon, radius, elevation)
    );

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(shapeVertices);

    return geometry;
  };

  const generateCountryLines = () => {
    return geoJson.features.flatMap((feature, index) => {
      const { type, coordinates } = feature.geometry;
      const countryName = feature.properties.name;
      let color = "#e4e4e7"; // Default color

      if (countryName === "Poland") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Germany") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Belarus") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "France") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Italy") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Spain") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Portugal") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Netherlands") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      } else if (countryName === "Belgium") {
        color = "#ef4444";
      }

      const countryGroup = new THREE.Object3D();

      if (type === "Polygon") {
        const geometry = createCountryBorders(coordinates);
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color });
        const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        countryGroup.add(line);
      } else if (type === "MultiPolygon") {
        coordinates.forEach((polygon) => {
          const geometry = createCountryBorders(polygon);
          const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color });
          const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
          countryGroup.add(line);
        });
      } else {
        console.warn("Unsupported geometry type:", type);
      }

      return <primitive key={index} object={countryGroup} />;
    });
  };

  return (
    <group ref={meshRef}>
      <mesh>
        <sphereGeometry args={[radius, 64, 64]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color="#7dd3fc" wireframe={false} />
      </mesh>
      {generateCountryLines()}
    </group>
  );
}

export default Globe;


Tried to use different tree js component but none seemed to work properly
UPD
I found some sort of semi solution that looks like this:
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { json } from "d3-fetch";
import earcut from "earcut";

function Globe() {
  const meshRef = useRef();
  const [geoJson, setGeoJson] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    json(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson"
    )
      .then((data) => {
        setGeoJson(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching GeoJSON:", error));
  }, []);

  useFrame(() => {
    if (meshRef.current) {
      meshRef.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
    }
  });

  if (!geoJson) return null;

  const radius = 5; // Radius of the globe
  const elevation = 0.02; // Increased elevation above the globe surface to prevent z-fighting

  const latLonToVector3 = (lat, lon, radius, elevation = 0) => {
    const phi = (90 - lat) * (Math.PI / 180);
    const theta = (lon + 180) * (Math.PI / 180);

    const x = -(radius + elevation) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    const y = (radius + elevation) * Math.cos(phi);
    const z = (radius + elevation) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

    return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
  };

  const createCountryGeometry = (coordinates) => {
    const vertices = [];
    const holeIndices = [];
    let holeIndex = 0;

    coordinates.forEach((polygon, index) => {
      polygon.forEach(([lon, lat]) => {
        const vector = latLonToVector3(lat, lon, radius, elevation);
        vertices.push(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
      });
      if (index > 0) {
        holeIndices.push(holeIndex);
      }
      holeIndex += polygon.length;
    });

    const indices = earcut(vertices, holeIndices, 3);

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute(
      "position",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3)
    );
    geometry.setIndex(indices);
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    return geometry;
  };

  const generateCountryMeshes = () => {
    return geoJson.features.flatMap((feature, index) => {
      const { type, coordinates } = feature.geometry;
      const countryName = feature.properties.name;
      let color = "red"; // Default color

      if (countryName === "Russia") {
        color = "blue";
      } else if (countryName === "Germany") {
        color = "green";
      }

      const countryGroup = new THREE.Object3D();

      if (type === "Polygon") {
        const geometry = createCountryGeometry(coordinates);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color,
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
          polygonOffset: true,
          polygonOffsetFactor: -1,
          polygonOffsetUnits: -1,
        });
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        countryGroup.add(mesh);
      } else if (type === "MultiPolygon") {
        coordinates.forEach((polygon) => {
          const geometry = createCountryGeometry(polygon);
          const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            polygonOffset: true,
            polygonOffsetFactor: -1,
            polygonOffsetUnits: -1,
          });
          const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
          countryGroup.add(mesh);
        });
      } else {
        console.warn("Unsupported geometry type:", type);
      }

      return <primitive key={index} object={countryGroup} />;
    });
  };

  return (
    <group ref={meshRef}>
      <mesh>
        <sphereGeometry args={[radius, 64, 64]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color="lightblue" wireframe={false} />
      </mesh>
      {generateCountryMeshes()}
    </group>
  );
}

export default Globe;

but the problem with this one is that result looks like this:
example 1
example 2
by some reason some parts of filling is dropping under the sphere mesh

That is classical z-issue problem and calculations layers in relation to sphere. Is those areas has to be some way dynamic, let say? If not, why don’t you use glb? Is much more easier and cleaner. Look at this example as well https://codesandbox.io/embed/6oei7?codemirror=1
